# What is mAP in object detection?

Tags: computer-vision, accuracy, object-detection, image-preprocessing

I have been reading through this [blog](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173) in order to find what mAP is .In the sub heading of AP, they give the example of 5 apple images and finding out the average precision.As far I understand false positive is when the object is localised and classified but IOU < 0.5 (in the blog) and false negative is when the model fails to identify an object itself.So what about objects which are misclassified dont they belong to false postives?.

Also what does the table in the blog really respresent.The 'correct?' is for one particluar example or 5 examples together.Could you just brief me what is going on in your own terms or just what the blog says?

Comment: Regarding your first question: I believe the usual setting involves computing average precision for a _single_ class. In your apple example, the detector outputs _(i)_ a box and _(ii)_ the probability of the box _containing an apple_.  So the detector cannot misclassify in the usual sense, of predicting a different class (say orange) for the given box.